# How can I add more button presses in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-tv

So I have been developing an android application and so far, it is going well. I have read the official documentation which points me [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv) to fire key press events. Currently the keys are limited and I was wondering how I can input more keys and how the core of it all works. I have managed to get to the `RCTTVRemoteHandler.m` file and I can see these lines of code:

```
NSString *const RCTTVRemoteEventMenu = @"menu";
NSString *const RCTTVRemoteEventPlayPause = @"playPause";
NSString *const RCTTVRemoteEventSelect = @"select";`

`//Play/Pause
    [self addTapGestureRecognizerWithSelector:@selector(playPausePressed:)
                                    pressType:UIPressTypePlayPause
                                         name:RCTTVRemoteEventPlayPause];`

`- (void)playPausePressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)r
{
  [self sendAppleTVEvent:RCTTVRemoteEventPlayPause toView:r.view];
}
```

I lack the understanding and due to low knowledge of how this works, I am curious to know how this can be achieved. I have a custom built android device with different keys which you'd normally not have on a simple android box. So I want to utilize some of the keys. The problem is that I have used keyevent manager packages in the past but adding those packages somehow ruins the current navigation and my keyboard no longer works with those packages. If someone could help me and point me somewhere, that would be great

Comment: You code is for iOS, not Android.

Comment: Yes I know. Could not find the Android version of this. Or I might have missed it. But it was surely intended for both IOS and Android as I can use the example of the documentation and press “left” to do an action